# Django MPTT. Получение листов

Tags: python, django

Доброго времени суток.

Django v.2.0.6
Django-mptt v.0.9.0

Имею структуру:

```
Раздел
|
+--Подраздел
   |
   +--Категория
       |
       +--Подкатегория-1
       +--Подкатегория-2
       +--Подкатегория-3
```

Находясь в **Подразделе** (или выше), могу получить листы средствами *Django-MPTT* не прибегая к написанию циклов/рекурсий?

Если нет, то какой подход посоветуете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
category = Category.objects.get(pk=take_id)
leafs = [i for i in category.objects.get_descendants() if i.is_leaf_node()]
```

**UPDATE:** Так должно быть эффективнее

```
ids = (Category.objects
               .filter(parent_id=take_id, children__isnull=True)
               .values_list('id', flat=True))

materials = Material.objects.filter(category_id__in=ids)
```

Comment: Модель `Category`, вместо **подраздел** указываю **Category.objects.get(id=take_id)**,  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sergey, `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` - указывает на `for`. Даже после вашей правки.

Comment: Опечатка, исправил.

Comment: Всё отлично Sergey, нужно только перед `for` аргумент `i` добавить. Но вы уже исправили). Могу ещё лично вам вопрос задать? Вы как профи, можете ответить. Вот я получаю список листов. Далее этот список использую, чтобы получить все материалы, которые входят в эти категории. Затем конкатенация и вывод. Я "облегчаю" запрос, получая не все поля. Мой подход правильный если, к примеру, будет 50 листов с 100.000 материалов в каждом и более?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Если он вам помог, [отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).